# ASP.NET XMLHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-ajax

how to identify on the server-side code behind page, that an XMLHttpRequest is made from client side?
IsPostBack will be false, but IsAsync, IsCallback are not affected.. 
IsPostBack will be false during first time page load also.. so is there any way to identify XMLHttpRequest accurately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom header `xhr.setRequestHeader('source', 'XmlHttpRequest')` that you can read in your code behind to detect XmlHttpRequests.

Comment: I am not been able to set requestHeader.. following error ----uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:50984/WebSite7/XHR.aspx :: populate :: line 35" data: no]-----

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function populate(textStr) {
            xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
            var url = "http://localhost:50984/WebSite7/XHR.aspx";
            url = url + "?q=" + textStr;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('source', 'XmlHttpRequest');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "MyCustomUser");
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
....

Comment: xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('source', 'XmlHttpRequest');

Comment: hello, Thanks a lot.. It worked.. before setting the requestHeader, it should have been opened..ie.--xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true)